# How to multiply all entries of column X by a constant, where X is a variable

Tags: python, numpy

Given X and a numpy array with D dimensions, how do I multiply all entries of column X by C. For example, consider the 3D case below:

If X = 0, the desired command would be

```
M[1,::]*=C
```

If X = 1, the desired command would be

```
M[:,1,:]*=C
```

If X = 2, the desired command would be

```
M[::,1]*=C
```

How would I code this so that it works in general?
Thanks!

Comment: I take it you mean `M[1, :, :]` not `M[1, ::]` and `M[:, :, 1]` not `M[::, 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is

```
M.swapaxes(0, X)[1] *= C
```